# How to use "SaveChanges" after upgrading EF Core 2.1 to 3.1

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

- I found the behavior of the "SaveChanges" has been changed after upgrade EFCore from 2.1 to 3.1:
- It could not be set the foreign key correctly in order to form the associations between entites in the creating scenario, and it seems related to this [breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes?toc=/dotnet/core/compatibility/toc.json&bc=/dotnet/breadcrumb/toc.json#temporary-key-values-are-no-longer-set-onto-entity-instances).
  ** "Temporary key values are no longer set onto entity instances" **
- Here is the my code snippet, it just simply create an new A entity and B entity, which there is one-To-many relationship between A and B, B has an navigate property "A_Id" and declaring the DB constrain in AutoMapp Class.

```
public class A
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public long a_Id { get;set; }
    public A a { get;set; }
}

public class BMap
{
    builder.HasForeignKey(x => x.A_Id)
           .HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.B_dbo.A_AId");
}

using (var context = _contextFactory.Create())
{
    A a;
    if (aDto.IsTransient)
    {
        a = context.AttachAsAdded<ADto>(aDto);
    }
    //await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    foreach (var bId in aDto.bIds)
    {
        context.AttachAsAdded(new B { a_Id = a.Id });
    }
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public TEntity AttachAsAdded<TEntity>(SimpleEntity dto)
            where TEntity : Entity, new()
        {
            var autoDetectChangesEnabled = ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled;
            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            var entity = new TEntity();
            var entry = Entry(entity);
            entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(dto);
            entry.State = EntityState.Added;

            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = autoDetectChangesEnabled;
            return entity;
        }
```

- In fact, EFCore will try to execute the SQL with assigning the foreign key (a_Id) as it's initial value of a.Id which is an negative number.
- And It throws an Exception in my case:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.B_dbo.A_AId". The conflict occurred in database "XXXX", table "dbo.A", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.”
```

- As a workaround, I solved it by executing "SaveChangeAsync" before I use the value which is generated by DB. (the commented line above)
- Please help me if there is any other way to solve it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why ? AttatchAsAdded? Have you seen any examples using this sort of custom implementations? I don't think so, take a look at the actual way of working with ef-core https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/adding-data

Comment: The idea of EF is that you just set `B.A` and don't worry about key values.

Comment: I have try only set B.A, but it still not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the code; *but it still not work* isn't really meaningful feedback. Also, please remove your first comment.